# Why are some functions available without having to load their parent package?

Tags: front-end, packages

Functions such as `GraphDistanceMatrix[]` or `AdjacencyMatrix[]` are available without invoking

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
```

.

Why isn't the whole package available when *Mathematica* starts? Are the functions different after having loaded `GraphUtilities`?

Comment: Those are simply different functions with the same name.  The package was available in older versions, the built-in functions are new in 8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at their `Context`s, you'll see that all of them are in the `` System` `` context and not the `` GraphUtilities` `` context.

```
Context /@ {GraphDistanceMatrix, CharacteristicPolynomial, AdjacencyMatrix}
Out[1]= {"System`", "System`", "System`"}
```

Some packages are preloaded when the kernel starts — `` System` `` is one of them, whereas `` GraphUtilities` `` is not. You can see all packages that are pre-loaded with `$Packages`

```
$Packages
Out[2]= {"ResourceLocator`", "DocumentationSearch`", "GetFEKernelInit`",
    "JLink`", "PacletManager`", "WebServices`", "System`", "Global`"}
```

Comment: @CHM: Which functions are you concerned about. For `CharacteristicPolynomial`, for example, it $must$ be the `System``` context because evaluating `?GraphUtilities``*` does not show any function of the same name in that context.

Comment: @murray I've noticed that `CharacteristicPolynomial[]` is not in `GraphUtilities`. Edited, thanks. I'm concerned not with a particular example, but with the fact that some functions might have two different definitions when loading a package.

Comment: @CHM: Yes, multiple definitions can be a problem. This seems to happen mostly with add-on packages that are still shipped with Mathematica but whose functions have not yet been moved into the kernel. 

Of course if you load a package and get shadowing messages, that's a sure tip-off. And you can always qualify the name of a function provided in a package by including the package's context when calling it.